# ESLint: types for `eslintrc.js`

Tags: eslint, typing, eslintrc, typescript-eslint, typescript-definitions

I want my `eslintrc.js` to be typechecked, and to have all the type definitions of allowed rules builtin.

i.e. like:

```
module.exports = defineESLint({
  rules: {
    // intellisence: Enforce the consistent use of either backticks, double, or single quotes
    // quotes?: 'off' | 'warn' | 'error'
    // | ['warn' | 'error', 'single' | 'double', { avoidEscape?: true }]
    quotes: ["warn", 'single', {avoidEscape: true}],
  }
})
```

And I generally want this to work with *all* my eslint extensions

Currently all I can do is

```
{
  "$schema": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SchemaStore/schemastore/master/src/schemas/json/eslintrc.json",
  "rules": {
    "quotes": [
      "warn",
      "single",
      {
        "avoidEscape": true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

in json, but it barely works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[npm:eslint-define-config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-define-config)

usage:

`.eslintrc.js`

```
// @ts-check
const { defineConfig } = require('eslint-define-config');

module.exports = defineConfig({
  root: true,
  rules: {
    // rules...
  },
});
```

---

Improve your eslint configuration experience with:

- auto-suggestions
- type checking (Use `// @ts-check` at the first line in your `.eslintrc.js`)
- documentation
- deprecation warnings

[image]